# I'm getting error while sorting data using specific column values

Tags: excel, vba

Here I want to sort data Range(A1:K17) using data in I column data.. But here I'm getting error:

> RUNTIME ERROR 1004 APPLICATION DEFINED

at last line before `End Sub`.. Can anyone help me?

```
Sub MySort()

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("DataSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1:K" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("I1:I" & LastRow), _
   Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `LastRow = Worksheets("DataSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is not fully qualified with `Worksheets("DataSheet")` , it needs to be `LastRow = Worksheets("DataSheet").Cells(Worksheets("DataSheet").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my machine, provided `DataSheet` is active and selected. To ensure that this works regardless, you need to qualify the sheet fully across your sort statement:

```
Sub MySort()

Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("DataSheet")
   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   .Range("A1:K" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("I1:I" & LastRow), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you are missing a little `.` - `.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` should be `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Thanks @ShaiRado, I've added it in.

Comment: Here "With Worksheets("DataSheet")"  by using this function we are able to get only static.. Can you please help me to   get dynamic result i.e for any worksheet..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully qualify all your objects related to `Worksheets("DataSheet")`.

```
LastRow = Worksheets("DataSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

and:

```
Range("A1:K" & LastRow)
```

In fact, it's easier to use a `With Worksheets("DataSheet")` statement.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MySort()

Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("DataSheet")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A1:K" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("I1:I" & LastRow), _
                                 Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End With

End Sub
```